# Windows CMD for matching files to directories

Tags: batch-file, cmd, matching

I have a Windows CMD script that has a bug. The script is supposed to match the first 8 digits (the date) of a file with a directory titled with the same first 8 digits (the date). If successful, the file is moved into that directory & placed in a subfolder (called 'portfolio'). However, the error File not Found is returned.

```
file: 20230202_example.jpg
directory: 20230202_winter-holiday/portfolio
```

...the CMD file:

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d') do (
  set "filename=%%a"
  set "first8=!filename:~0,8!"
  for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir /b /a-d *%first8%*') do (
    if /i "!filename!" neq "%%b" ( 
    move "!filename!" "%%b\portfolio\!filename!"
    )
  )
)
```

If I interrogate the directory in Command Prompt:

```
dir /b /a-d
```

...I get a full list of the files contained. When the script is run from Command Prompt, for each file contained I get:

```
File Not Found
```

Comment: Yo need a line `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` directly after the `@echo off` line. This invokes `delayedexpansion` which allows access to the run-time value of variables via `!var!`. WIthout the `setlocal` line, `!` is an ordinary character, so you are looking for a filename containing `!` characters (and others). You also need to use `!first8!`, not `%first8%` because you are varying the value of `first8` within the loop Beware of the [delayed expansion trap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947)

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your target file and directory names, you could probably do it without defining variables and therefore the need to delay variable expansion.

Example:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Dir "????????_*" /A:-D /B 2^>NUL
 ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /C:"^202[0123]1[012][12][0123456789]_."
 /C:"^19[789][0123456789]0[123456789]0[123456789]_."
 /C:"^19[789][0123456789]0[123456789][12][0123456789]_."
 /C:"^19[789][0123456789]0[123456789]3[01]_." /C:"^202[0123]0[123456789]3[01]_."
 /C:"^19[789][0123456789]1[012]0[123456789]_."
 /C:"^19[789][0123456789]1[012][12][0123456789]_."
 /C:"^19[789][0123456789]1[012]3[01]_." /C:"^20[01][0123456789]1[012]3[01]_."
 /C:"^20[01][0123456789]0[123456789]0[123456789]_." /C:"^202[0123]1[012]3[01]_."
 /C:"^20[01][0123456789]0[123456789][12][0123456789]_."
 /C:"^20[01][0123456789]0[123456789]3[01]_."
 /C:"^20[01][0123456789]1[012]0[123456789]_."
 /C:"^20[01][0123456789]1[012][12][0123456789]_."
 /C:"^202[0123]0[123456789]0[123456789]_." /C:"^202[0123]1[012]0[123456789]_."
 /C:"^202[0123]0[123456789][12][0123456789]_."
 ') Do For /F "Delims=_" %%H In ("%%~nG") Do For /F "Delims=" %%I In ('
 Dir "%%H_*" /A:D /B 2^>NUL'
) Do %SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe . "%%I\portfolio" "%%G" /Mov 1>NUL 2>&1
```

I decided to use a little more accuracy in the dates, *(it's not perfect because it has no knowlege of how many days are in each month of any year, but should cover dates between 19700101 and 20231231)*. If you don't want that, you could simplify it by just removing lines 4 through 17:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Dir "????????_*" /A:-D /B 2^>NUL
 ') Do For /F "Delims=_" %%H In ("%%~nG") Do For /F "Delims=" %%I In ('
 Dir "%%H_*" /A:D /B 2^>NUL'
) Do %SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe . "%%I\portfolio" "%%G" /Mov 1>NUL 2>&1
```